# Magento Admin - add new row order totals

Tags: magento-1.9

I am a newbie in Magento development.

**Do you know how to add a new row to totals in admin order view to show the resulting computation of subtotal + shipping?**

I create path folder with Sketchkode/Totalgst/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
   <global>
      <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
             <sales_order_totals>Sketchkode_Totalgst_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Totals</sales_order_totals>
      </rewrite>
      </adminhtml>
   </blocks>
</global>
```

After I create Based on config   Sketchkode/Totalgst/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Totals.php

```
<?php
  class Sketchkode_Totalgst_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Totals extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Totals{
     /**
     * Initialize order totals array
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Totals
      */
     protected function _initTotals()
     {

      parent::_initTotals();
       $order_id=$this->getOrder()->getId(); 


     $amount=5; 

    if ($amount) {
        $this->addTotalBefore(new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'      => 'fee',
            'value'     => $amount,
            'base_value'=> $amount,
            'label'     => $this->helper('sales')->__('Fee'),
        ), array('shipping', 'tax')));
 }

    return $this;
   }
}
```

I get blank Order Totals

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were be three possible problem of That

1. You missed spelled the directory name
2. cache problem (delete the cache)
3. **'code'      => 'fee',** your code is already used by other ext so changes it something unique code.